# How do I make a program where you can communicate with other language CORBA?

Tags: corba

I must make a program which implements the CORBA client and server in some other language, but i don´t know like it.

Comment: I decided to do it with python and c, and had very good results with the famous omniORB, I upload the link of a basic calculator in CORBA https://mega.co.nz/#!xQ8kBZDI!JYJdrVfBAwxLBsal52h79TQa3W1VZP35GQsaQ8OMDCw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step is that you decide which programming language you want to use, than search for an implementation for that language, like [TAO](https://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/~schmidt/TAO.html) for C++, [R2CORBA](https://www.remedy.nl/opensource/r2corba.html) for Ruby/JRuby, [JacORB](http://www.jacorb.org/) for Java, [TAOX11](https://www.taox11.org) for C++11. Than you have to write your IDL and implement the CORBA client and server. Each CORBA implemention ships with a set of example applications, use those as starting point.

Comment: I decided to do it with python and c, and had very good results with the famous omniORB, I upload the link of a basic calculator in CORBA